# Finding point inside parallelogram closest to given point

Tags: geometry

For an arbitrary parallelogram and an arbitrary point (outside the parallelogram), I want to find the point on one of the parallelogram's edges that is closest to given point.

[Example Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfy6n.png)

In the above example, the closest point for P1 would be on the line AD. You could find this point by intersecting a line going through P1 and being normal to AD with AD. For P2, the closest point would be D.

I have no idea how to find the closest edge though, or whether or not an edge would be closer than a point. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the problem by finding the closest point on a **line segment** to any given point, and solve the problem four times for each edge of the parallelogram.

For each edge (from e.g. point `A` to point `B`):

1. Project `P` onto the "extended" line `g`, parameterized as `g = A + t * (AB)`
2. At the projected point, `t` will be `(AP x AB) / |AP|^2`

   - If `t <= 0`, the closest point is `A`.
   - If `t >= 1`, the closest point is `B`.
   - Else, the closest point is `A + t * (AB)` with `t` calculated as above.

Then all you need to do is calculate the distance from `P` to every of the four closest points on each edge, and choose the one with the smallest distance.

The answer is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment).

Answer (score 1):

At each vertex of the parallelogram, there are two edges that meet.  Construct a perpendicular to each of these edges going through the given vertex, and extend that perpendicular out to infinity.  This will divide the plane into a series of sectors, with long "semi-infinite rectangles" areas reaching out from each side, separated by "wedges" with a point at each vertex at the parallelogram.

[image]

Any point that lies inside one of the "semi-infinite rectangles" will be closest to the edge at the "base" of that rectangle;  any point that lies in one of the "wedges" will be closest to the point at the base of that wedge.

This will work for any convex polygon, by the way—not just parallelograms.

Comment: Very nice illustration, I drew a similar sketch already. The problem, however, is to decide whether the point lies within a "semi-infinite rectangle" or "wedge", and which one.

Comment: @OverrideApps: Are you specifying $P$ and the parallelogram by Cartesian coordinates?  From your original question, I assumed you were just looking for a geometric construction;  if you want an analytic-geometry type of answer instead, you might want to edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I need to actually compute P and yes I am using cartesian coordinates. I've found a solution which I'll post tomorrow. Thanks for your help though.